# What does the word "evening-in" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word "evening-in" in the following sentence from the description of the game Golf Clash:

> Mark Twain described golf as “a good walk spoiled”, but you should
>   think of Golf Clash as an **evening-in** enhanced.

I could not find a single entry of the word "evening-in" in dictionaries.

For some context, here is a brief description of the game from a different source:

> In the game, players compete against each other in real-time,
>   turn-based golf matches of about 4-5 minutes that feel like contests
>   of Golden Tee, the classic bar room arcade game.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The meaning of "evening-in" here is an evening spent at home. The claim is that one's evening spent at home will be enhanced by playing the game. "Evening-in" won't be in a dictionary, because it's a "nonce word", created in the moment of writing for just that use. The writer used a hyphen to make it clear that he intended the collocation to be regarded as a noun, meaning an evening spent at home. The entire phrase "an evening-in enhanced" is intended to be parallel to Mark Twain's "a good walk spoiled".

Comment: I've heard an "evening in" and an "evening out" many times before, so to me at least it isn't a nonce word, unless you are perhaps referring specifically to the hypenated form. Might be a good question for sister site English Language & Usage.

Comment: I did mean the hyphenated form, which I think prevents the possible garden path of "...  in enhanced ? ". The compound also becomes a noun followed by a participle adjective (enhanced), more parallel to "a good walk spoiled".

Comment: It may also be the case that modern standards for hyphenation seem quite relaxed (or at least very different) compared to prior usages. Modern usage seems a bit rare, and I doubt I'll ever see "to-morrow" outside of an older piece of writing.

Comment: @JW: It's is generally accepted to use hyphens (when the defined words themselves do not normally contain them) if it disambiguates the structure of the sentence, as is the case here.

Comment: Of course they could have just written _enhanced evening in_ and avoided the problem entirely.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ... That would lose the parallelism with the Twain quote.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty He'll get over it ;)

Answer (score 19):

I haven't seen it hyphenated before, but it clearly means "an evening in", i.e. "an evening spent at home".

Comment: The movie make this impossible to find. +1

Comment: @Mazura: which movie?

Comment: The hyphen expresses what is enhanced is the evening (spent) in(side). If it was not hyphenated, then I would read "...as an evening in enhanced" and it would seem incomplete (as if "enhanced" was an adjective without a paired noun). An evening in an enhanced what? Enhanced bliss? Interestingly, I think if it had read "...as an enhanced evening in" (ie, without the hyphen) I would understand it because there is nothing after the "in" which implies the correct sense.

Comment: Yes, I can see why it's been done. But it's not usual. I think if I were writing it, I would put a comma after "in", instead.

Comment: @JW - [An Evening in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Evening_in_Paris) - The first three hits if you google *an evening in*, with three clips of the movie in the way on top. Google has learned that when I search I'm looking for a definition. With this it's as bad Siri trying to sell me stuff on iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into trouble looking up "evening-in" because it's not actually what most people would say.  If you enter `"an evening in"` (with the quotes) into Google, you get 5.31M hits (with or without the hyphen).  If you enter `"a night in"` you get 48.6M and the very first hit is a definition of the phrase.  Note that I made a point of including the article (an/a), because it is part of the idiom.  Using articles in English -- not merely correctly, but colloquially -- is important if you want to master the language.